# Angular show button and area only if i select an option

Tags: java, angular

I wouldlike to show button or a table only if i selected an option:

Picture :
[image]

My code :

.html

```html
<div class="liste">
  <select class="form-control" name="Container" (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an Container -- </option>
    <option *ngFor="let v of values;let i = index" [value]="i">
      {{v.Name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="tableau">
  <table align="center">
    <tr align="center"><b>{{selectedValue.Name}}</b></tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Matricule: {{selectedValue.Matricule}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Material: {{selectedValue.Material}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Quantity: {{selectedValue.Quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Coordonates: {{selectedValue.Coordonates}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">Generationp</button>
```

My file .ts :

```
selectedValue = {
        Name: '',
        Matricule: '',
        Material:'',
        Quantity:'',
        Coordonates:'',
    }
    values = [{
        Name: "Container A",
        Matricule: "ABC",
    },
    {
        Name: "Container B",
        Matricule: "BCD",
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can use *ngIf="show" on button and table.
Set "show" value as true or false on click or change event of select.

.html
----------
    <div class="liste">
  <select class="form-control" name="Container" (change)="setShowTrue($event.target.value)">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an Container -- </option>
    <option *ngFor="let v of values;let i = index" [value]="v.Name">
      {{v.Name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div *ngIf="show" class="tableau">
  <table align="center">
    <tr align="center"><b>{{selectedValue.Name}}</b></tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Matricule: {{selectedValue.Matricule}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Material: {{selectedValue.Material}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Quantity: {{selectedValue.Quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>Coordonates: {{selectedValue.Coordonates}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button *ngIf="show" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">Generationp</button>

.ts
--------

show: boolean = false;
    setShowTrue(name: any){
      console.log(name);
      this.show = true;
    }
```

Comment: How can set "show" value as true or false on event of select ?

Answer (score 1):

you can store selected value of dropdown in a ngmodel and use it to show / hide table using `ngIf` as shown below

```
<div class="liste">
                <select class="form-control" name="Container" (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an Container -- </option>
                    <option *ngFor="let v of values;let i = index" [value]="i">
                        {{v.Name}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>

    <div class="tableau" *ngIf="selectedValue!=''">
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr align="center"><b>{{selectedValue.Name}}</b></tr>
                        <tr align="center"><td>Matricule: {{selectedValue.Matricule}}</td></tr>
                        <tr align="center"><td>Material: {{selectedValue.Material}}</td></tr>
                        <tr align="center"><td>Quantity: {{selectedValue.Quantity}}</td></tr>
                        <tr align="center"><td>Coordonates: {{selectedValue.Coordonates}}</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">Generationp</button>
```

The .ts :

```
selectedValue = '';
    values = [{
        Name: "Container A",
        Matricule: "ABC",
    },
    {
        Name: "Container B",
        Matricule: "BCD",
    }
```

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work for me. It's hide my option value (and I woudlike to hide table and my button)

Comment: Ideally it should work, please check modal selectedValue value is getting updated properly after you change / select value from dropdown

Comment: hope you have set ngmodal variable in your component first before using it in HTML. If not then please see this https://appdividend.com/2018/10/03/angular-ngmodel-directive-example-tutorial/

Comment: I just edited my post with a party of my .ts file I don't understand vert well how ng model works

Comment: looks like you have edited by post instead of your but no problem, i have edited your question properly. Please see updated answer, where i have shown how i have added  `selectedValue` for ngmodal.

Comment: I have this error : Type '{ Name: string; Matricule: string; Material: string; Quantity: string; Coordonates: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: maybe it because I have this method : `selectChangeHandler(event) {
  this.selectedValue = this.values[event.target.value];`

}